# How to remove background box for active li element in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to remove background box for selected active li element but unable to do it here is my code for bootstrap, the background  is coming in the colour grey I want to immediately remove that one, I tried all the options Here is my code

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #204264;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}


.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff ;

}



.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
 color: #f4511e !important;
  /*background-color: #fff !important;*/
}



 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
 color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: If using V3, you may fix it up at line no. 4521, with these selectors - 
`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{}`

Comment: But I would suggest you not to make changes in bootstrap file itself, better override it within your styles.css(or any other css file you're using), having your own selector classes.

Answer (score 0):

just remove  .navbar-nav li.active a  in this line

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
```

use

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover{
```

This will apply only cursor moved on li . If you don't want that also remove this one .

```
navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
 color: #f4511e !important;
  /*background-color: #fff !important;*/
}
```

Comment: Still, it is showing the grey background with white colour text